# Elasticsearch - fetch matching words based on case insensitive

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fuzzy-search

Am fetching documents from elasticsearch indexes and am using `whitespace` tokenizer with stemmer.

Please find my mapping file below.

```
PUT stemmer_lower_test
 {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
           "value_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
           ],
           "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "my_stemmer"]
         }
       },
       "filter" : {
                "my_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "name" : "minimal_english"
                }
         }
     }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "product_attr_value": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "value_analyzer"
          },
          "product_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "product_name":{
          "type": "text"
          }

        }
       }
      }
}
```

Please find my fuzzy API which am using :

```
QueryBuilder qb1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("product_attr_value", keyword).boost(0.0f).prefixLength(3).fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO).transpositions(true));
```

If am searching for `value` (in lowercase) and getting count arround `1555`. If i searching for  `Value` (only first character in uppercase) and getting `8979` count.

Am expecting both count should be same. like i want to search with case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy Query is a term level query, then, Elasticsearch won't apply any analyzer on your search term. You have to normalize it before submitting your search to ES. It's the same for multiple other query types.

> While the full text queries will analyze the query string before executing, the term-level queries operate on the exact terms that are stored in the inverted index

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html